# What are morphisms between regularity structures?

Tags: ct.category-theory, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-paths, regularity-structures

In Hairer's notes [A Theory of Regularity Structures](http://www.hairer.org/papers/Structure.pdf) he defines automorphisms of a regularity structure on page 28. I will recall the definition here:

[image]

Is there any way of extending this to morphisms between different regularity structures? For example, one would probably want the polynomial regularity structure in $d$ variables to embed into the polynomial regularity structure of $d+1$ variables, right?

Is there a coherent way to define morphisms between different regularity structures? If so, what does the category of regularity structures look like? Does it have any interesting properties?

Comment: This is a bit late, but perhaps it is still helpful. Notice that there is a notion of extension of regularity structure, together with the notion of automorphisms this should give the idea of automorphisms between the case polynomial regularity structures for different values of d.

Comment: More than that, the set Hairer defines as $Aut \mathscr{T}$ is not an exhaustive list of the automorphisms of the model space (together invariance of the structure group via conjugation with the map). Indeed, in essence the maps $M$ are such that elements of $T_\alpha$ are mapped into new elements "with a strictly positive and finite gain in regularity". One should be able to translate these ideas between different regurality structures.

Comment: However, the main uses for these automorphisms is to study renormalisation of regularity of models to give an idea invariance to models defined in regularity structures. Most of the times, we fix the regularity structure at the very beginning of the argument (perhaps with some extensions to make sure it contains all the symbols you need) and study convergence of different models for the same structure. Therefore, we end up almost never worrying with more than one regularity structure at time.

Comment: [1/n] What would that be useful for ? I suppose that with an application in mind you would naturally see what definition you need. Note that as mentioned by Hairer automorphisms need not be invertible when $A$ is infinite -and $L_0^+$ is not necessarily nilpotent. We would have to relax $M\Gamma M^-1$ to $M\Gamma = \Gamma'M$ for some $\Gamma'$ In the example of polynomials inclusion into polynomials with 1 more variable translations $\Gamma'$ is any translation by a point which projects to the original $\Gamma$. The idea is that $G$ are canonical automorphisms and they are preserved, actually

Comment: [2/n] for a fixed $M$ "the" $\Gamma'$ can probably be given by an embedding of $G_1$ into $G_2$ -for $M$ an automorphism it is conjugation by $M$. Further the definition of an automorphism is given as a composition of a nilpotent linear map and an invertible semisimple grading-preserving linear map. So we could relax the the invertibility on the semisimple part, $S$, keeping the grading preservation. The nilpotent part is already arbitary (at least for finite $A$) in the definition of automorphism so we don't have to relax. We end up with an endomorphism being $S\circ L$ with $L\in L_0^+$.

Comment: [3/n, n=3] Now we can compose inclusions with endomorphisms and projections. Between finite-dimensional $T_1\rightarrow T_2$ this should be enough to obtain all morphisms defined in a better way that i can't define now. For infinite-dimensional T i can't guess now -though it's probably trivial.

PS: Im only learning the basics of regularity strutures so i have 0 insight into possible uses or "correctness" of the above, i'm just aiding my learning by writing.